# AWS Java SDK (API Gateway): How to disable an API key

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-java-sdk

Hi I am trying to disable an API key programmatically, but can't find any documentation.

So far I have located 2 classes that might be what I need:

UpdateApiKeyRequest and DeleteApiKeyRequest. Problem is that I have no clue what to do with these.

Please could someone show me how to use these classes to disable or delete an API key?

Answer (score 7):

You can use deleteApiKey API.

The SDK source code is available [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-api-gateway/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/apigateway/AmazonApiGateway.java#L251). The documentation is available [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/apigateway/AmazonApiGateway.html#deleteApiKey(com.amazonaws.services.apigateway.model.DeleteApiKeyRequest)).

**Update:**

You can disable an API Key using updateApiKey API.

The SDK is documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/apigateway/AmazonApiGateway.html#updateApiKey(com.amazonaws.services.apigateway.model.UpdateApiKeyRequest)). The API reference is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/link-relation/apikey-update/).

The below is a sample PatchOperations object to be sent in the PATCH request:

```
{"patchOperations":[{"op":"replace","path":"/enabled","value":"false"}]}
```

Comment: Thanks, that should do the trick. Do you know how I would go about disabling a key instead of deleting a key?

I see there is an UpdateApiKeyRequest too, but I don't know what values to populate on it's PatchOperations member.

Comment: @DuranWesleyHarris: Updated the answer with the details for disabling the API Key.

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what I need

Comment: Ok I populated the PatchOperations object as you indicated but I get this error: 

com.amazonaws.services.apigateway.model.NotFoundException: Invalid Metering Id identifier specified (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NotFoundException; Request ID: 19c55e0e-fa2f-11e5-8958-7711b14a79a6)